# Rails - multiple models in one table(view). How to create redirected to edit depending on the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, haml, erb

I have this problem: In the project I combined most of the different models (eg Person, Gallery, Article ...) so that their common list is displayed in one view in the table.
Now, in haml I want to add edit actions: for each entry and make it redirect to the appropriate model.

I want something like this:

```
- @searches.each do |p|
  = link_to 'EDIT', edit_SOME_MODEL_path(p), class: 'a__link-btn'
```

So, It can be a lot of models:

```
= link_to 'EDIT', edit_person_path(p), class: 'a__link-btn'
= link_to 'EDIT', edit_news_article_path(p), class: 'a__link-btn'
= link_to 'EDIT', edit_order_path(p), class: 'a__link-btn'
= link_to 'EDIT', edit_news_article_path(p), class: 'a__link-btn'
= link_to 'EDIT', edit_movie_path(p), class: 'a__link-btn'
```

And when I click on the selected one, I want to be redirected depending on the model e.g.:
`http://localhost:3000/en/news_articles/2/edit`
or
`http://localhost:3000/en/persons/3/edit`

What is the best option for solution?

Comment: consider accepting/upvoting an answer if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [polymorphic routing helpers](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html):

```haml
- @searches.each do |p| 
  = link_to 'EDIT', [p, :edit], class: 'a__link-btn'
```

Comment: Yes. Polymorphic routing helper is solution for my problem.